# If my "Then I should see" Cucumber feature is failing, how can I see what Cucumber is seeing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

Presumably if Cucumber is not seeing what I expect it to see, it must be seeing something else. Mirroring in my application what I think the same steps are, I get the desired output.

This is a "signing in" feature. It appears that sign in is failing in the test. But unless I can see the error message, I don't know why it's failing!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cucumber has a step called "show me the page" that works great!  You can put it right where you want to view the page in your tests, like so:

```
  When I go to the sign in page
  Then show me the page # saves the HTML of that page and opens the file
  And I sign in as "email@person.com/password"
  Then I should see "Bad email or password"
  And I should be signed out
```

I believe you need the launchy gem to make this work.  Here's an article that describes it, along with other cool cucumber tricks:

http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/189412598/five-ridiculously-awesome-cucumber-and-webrat